# Problema ao tentar fazer upload de arquivos utilizando o primefaces 4.0

Tags: java, primefaces, file-upload

Eu tenho uma aplicação simples que permite eu fazer upload de arquivos textos. Para fazer esses uploads, estou usando o File Upload do Primefaces, mas estou tendo problemas. Já tentei diversas soluções e não consigo arrumar esse problema.

Essa aplicação é feita em cima do JPA, Spring 4, Spring Security, JSF 2.2 e Primefaces 4.0. Também uso a biblioteca do omnifaces como um helper para o JSF.

Quebrei a pergunta em diversos pedaços que acho estar relacionado a esse problema de upload do primefaces. Mas se precisarem de mais informações, me avisem para que eu complemente miha pergunta.

### As dependências Maven (pom.xml)

There are more dependencies declared, but I think only these are used by primefaces. If you need to view my entire pom.xml, let me know.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

### O arquivo web.xml

Somente as partes relevantes ao primefaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns=" http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>My App</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-context*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>aristo</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Protege os fontes das páginas JSF quando acessadas
            diretamente
        </display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>960</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jspa</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/app/errors/viewExpired.jspa</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/app/errors/error.jspa</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/app/errors/notfound.jspa</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

### O arquivo faces-config.xml (relacionado ao Spring e ao Omnifaces.).

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>

<faces-config-extension>
    <facelets-processing>
        <file-extension>.xhtml</file-extension>
        <process-as>xhtml</process-as>
    </facelets-processing>
</faces-config-extension>
```

### O arquivos XHTML.

Aqui é onde eu acho que pode estar o problema, mas não consigo achar.

```
<h:form id="uplFileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload id="uplFile"
                  fileUploadListener="#{myManagedBean.save}"
                  mode="advanced"
                  auto="true"
                  label="Select the file"
                  uploadLabel="Upload"
                  cancelLabel="Cancel"
                  invalidSizeMessage="File is too big"
                  invalidFileMessage="Format not supported"
                  dragDropSupport="false"
                  sizeLimit="614572800"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt|TXT)$/" />
</h:form>
```

### Meu Managed Bean

E aqui é onde está o método onde deveria receber o arquivo do upload e salva-lo em disco. O problema é que o meu método de salvamento do arquivo `save(FileUploadEvent)` **nunca é chamado**! Já tentei debug e a execução nunca chega a ele. Isso me leva a acreditar que o problema é antes, ou seja no XHTML.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyManagedBean extends AbstractMB implements Serializable {
    public void save(FileUploadEvent event) {
        try {
            String fileName = event.getFile().getFileName();

            MyFileUpload myFile = new MyFileUpload();
            byte[] content = event.getFile().getContents();

            myFile.setFilename(event.getFile().getFileName());
            myFile.setContent(conteudo);
            myFile.setChecksum(getHelperService().getCheckSum(content));
            save(myFile);
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex) {
            logger.error("Error, ex);
         }
    }
}
```

### A Exceção

E essa é a exceção que ocorre quando eu clico no botão de upload de arquivo. Nota que o erro ocorre e a barra de progresso nem se mexe!

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /myapp/app/admin/fileuploads/index.jspa: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.findErrorPageLocation(WebXml.java:176) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.findErrorPageLocation(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:270) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handleAjaxException(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:200) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handle(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:175) [omnifaces-1.7.jar:1.7]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.5-jbossorg-3.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
...
```

Comment: Ricardo, como está connfigurado seu `Faces Servlet` do `web.xml`?

Comment: Acabei de adicionar todo o meu `web.xml` @MiguelCartagena.

Comment: É difícil apontar algum problema aí. Tenta debugar colocando um breakpoint no filter de upload do primefaces. Porque o erro é um NPE, então certamente você vai conseguir identificar qual objeto está nulo.

Comment: Infelizmente o PF não ajuda muito na questão de logs. O log aí não diz nada. Há alguma outra pilha ou log? Talvez isso possa dar uma dica da causa real do problema.

Comment: Outra coisa, não entendi essa configuração `<faces-config-extension>` no `faces-config`. Lá está com `xhtml` e no `web.xml` está `jspa`.

Comment: Então, @MiguelCartagena, é um NullPointerException, mas o método do meu MB nunca é chamado. Eu não consigo "parar" a execução. Parece ser algo interno do PF porque ele nem carrega o arquivo. A barra de progresso não evolui e já estoura o erro.

Comment: @utluiz, essa configuração que você citou é relacionada a geração do `<DOCTYPE>` no HTML. Vou explicar melhor. Por padrão, o JSF 2.2 gera o DOCTYPE do HTML 5, ou seja: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Porém, meu projeto está definindo no fonte dos XHTML o DOCTYPE "manualmente". Então eu preciso dizer ao JSF 2.2 não gerar o DOCTYPE padrão. Para isso uso essa configuração.

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti entendo que você não consegue colocar um breakpoint no seu código, mas você pode colocar no código do Primefaces, na classe `FileUploadFilter`. Como você vai fazer isso, depende da sua IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Por padrão o PrimeFaces 4.0 faz uma escolha entre o modo **native** e **commons**. Deve estar acontecendo algo inesperado nessa escolha. Para evitar isso, adicione o seguinte trecho no seu **web.xml** para usar a biblioteca Commons Fileupload que já está presente no seu projeto.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
   <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Assim o PrimeFaces deixa de fazer a escolha automática que é padrão.

Comment: EXCELENTE, Luídne Realmente funcionou perfeitamente após alterar o WEB.XML conforme mecionou. > <context-param> <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name> <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>